# Use AWS CloudFront for PHP site

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a site based on PHP called www.example.com. I setup a CloudFront Distributions. I put www.example.com in `Origin Domain Name` field. I took default values for most setup config. 
Now what's next? This distribution has a domain name `xxxxx.cloudfront.net`. But I cannot ask users to use `xxxxx.cloudfront.net` as my domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to point www.example.com to xxxxx.cloudfront.net by creating a C-Name record in the DNS where the domain is hosted.

Comment: Thanks. my example.com is registered with Go Daddy. So I need to login Go Daddy to create C-Name? I will try. I have no idea what is a C-Name. Let me find out.

Comment: Check this http://imgur.com/a/AcZQ9 in the @ field for your domain add the xxxxx.cloudfront.net

Comment: Thanks! Put `xxxxx.cloudfront.net` @field and put www.example.com in Host field? Or just leave `www` in Host field? There is a `www` in host field already.